# What is the effect of light, medium and heavy armor?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Armor in XCOM is described as being either light, medium, or heavy. What are the effects of wearing a particular type of armor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only gameplay difference is the Assault Class's major rank ability: Extra Conditioning.

For all other intents in purposes, armor type doesn't matter. Stick your Snipers in Titan, or your Heavies in Archangel - they'll get the maximal beneifts either way.